# Conditional Formatting- Getting cells to reference properly

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Not sure if this question is allowed, due to its more of an excel question than program question.

BUT

Essentially I have the following condition: =AND(ABS(S119) > 0.75, T119 = FALSE)

To be clear: I want to highlight the cells in column S when the absolute value of the number is greater than .75 AND when the cell to its right (column T) is FALSE....The condition works when I type in the proper cells and conditionally format it for that single cell...**I am trying to use this format through an entire column**, but the cells only reference the originally typed in cells...I've tried it in every combination of $ signs, and still it does not copy through.

I have the conditonal format with "Applies To" to =$S:$S (the whole column)

Can anyone help me with this (hopefully) basic excel problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were almost there, but you need to use this in your condition

=AND(ABS(S1) > 0.75,  $T1=FALSE)

the $T tells to tell excel condition to use T as a fixed reference to the column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was a combination of $, just couldn't figure out which combination. Well done.